# Width of input field won't reduce

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I've tried reducing my "Number of employees" input field to a size of "3" (all others have a size of "8").

**However my number of employees input field is not reducing it's length?**

Can anyone shed any light to as *why?*

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: "Arial", "Myriad Pro", "Myriad Web", "Tahoma", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
form header {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
form header div {
  font-size: 90%;
  color: #999;
}
form header h2 {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
form > div {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
form > div > fieldset > div > div {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
form > div > label,
legend {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
form > div > div,
form > div > fieldset > div {
  width: 75%;
  float: right;
}
form > div > fieldset label {
  font-size: 90%;
}
fieldset {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=url],
input[type=password],
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.6em;
  border-top: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  border-left: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  border-right: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
}
input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=url],
input[type=password] {
  width: 50%;
}
input[type=text]:focus,
input[type=email]:focus,
input[type=url]:focus,
input[type=password]:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-color: #4697e4;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  form > div {
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  }
  form > div > label,
  legend {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  }
  form > div > div,
  form > div > fieldset > div {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
  input[type=text],
  input[type=email],
  input[type=url],
  input[type=password],
  textarea,
  select {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  form > div > label,
  legend {
    text-align: right;
  }
}
/* JQuery Validation */

label.error,
select.error,
textarea.error,
input.error {
  padding-left: 5px;
  display: block;
  color: #f00;
}
label {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.loader {
  background: url("https://secure.workbooks.com/resources/=QzM/spinner_gray_160.gif") no-repeat center center transparent;
}
.notification {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgb(209, 224, 94);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: rgb(131, 6, 6);
}
.loudbutton,
.quietbutton {
  width: 60%;
  height: 40%;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background-color: rgb(79, 111, 163);
  border: none;
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  float: none;
}
.desc {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.grayborder {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.quietbutton {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.loudbutton {
  font-size: 1.35em;
}
.quietbutton {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
.loudbutton:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 60%;
  height: 40%;
  background-color: #84a3d9;
}
/* Sticky footer: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ */

#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
}
#main {
  overflow: auto;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
  /* must be same height as the footer */
}
#main-img {
  float: left;
}
#main-banner {
  float: right;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#main-body {
  clear: both;
}
/*Opera Fix*/

body:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  width: 0;
  margin-top: -32767px;
  /
}
/* Workbooks Attribution: please leave this */

#footer {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -45px;
  height: 45px;
  clear: both;
  background-image: url(https://secure.workbooks.com/images/logo/workbooks_logo.png);
  background-color: #80a0ff;
  background-position: center left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 119px 42px;
}
#workbooks-link {
  position: absolute;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url('https://secure.workbooks.com/images/s.gif');
  /* fix overlap error in IE7/8 */
}
/* Fade-in Spinner */

#spinner {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: url(https://public.workbooks.com/images/spinner.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat #ede9df;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <div>
    <label class="desc" id="title1" for="first_name">First Name</label>
    <div>
      <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" class="required field text fn" value="" size="8" tabindex="1" minlength="2" autofocus>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label class="desc" id="title2" for="last_name">Last Name</label>
    <div>
      <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text" class="required field text fn" value="" size="8" tabindex="2">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label class="desc" id="title3" for="email">Email</label>
    <div>
      <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="required email" spellcheck="false" value="" maxlength="255" tabindex="3">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label class="desc" id="title4" for="telephone">Telephone</label>
    <div>
      <input id="telephone" name="telephone" type="text" class="required field text fn" value="" size="8" tabindex="4">
    </div>
  </div>


  <div>
    <label class="desc" id="title5" for="number_of_employees">Number of Employees</label>
    <div>
      <input id="number_of_employees" tabindex="5" name="number_of_employees" type="text" class="required integer field text fn" pattern="[0-9]*" size="3" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label class="desc" id="title6" for="company_name">Company Name</label>
    <div>
      <input id="company_name" name="company_name" type="text" class="required field text fn" value="" size="8" tabindex="6">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <fieldset>


      <div>
        <div>
          <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Get access &#9658;" class="loudbutton" />
        </div>
      </div>

</form>
```

Comment: There's an option called `Tidy`. After doing it, you will understand that the last part is totally not well formed.

Comment: I could find everything in the same size here: http://www.bootply.com/E2cfd79REN.

Comment: Please explain Tidy more, I'm new here and already being down voted!

Comment: Sam, don't worry, $h!t happens for new people. Okay, when you tried adding your code for the first time, it looked way different than now right? So that's what I meant by check using Tidy. When you click on the edit snippet button in your [edit], you can find Tidy button there.

Comment: Thanks Praveen, a fickle bunch here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css rules are taking precedence and the size attribute is no longer considered, unless css is disabled.

In 1 of your css rules you define the width of an input as 50%, what you need is to create a "stronger" rule that will define the size for smaller inputs. You can do so by adding a class to the same rule that sets the initial width.

Add a new line after this code with:

```
input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=url],
input[type=password] {
  width: 50%;
}

/* new line - adjustment to smaller input fields */
input[type=text].size-small,
input[type=email].size-small,
input[type=url].size-small,
input[type=password].size-small {
  width: 25%;
}
```

and for the elements that you would like to assign size="3" add attribute class="size-small"

Comment: Did it work for you? If it did please up vote the answer to identify it as feasible.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/xKUxETY3gZ here is the code for you, in case you have any questions

Comment: Thanks again Alexander!

Comment: My pleasure, I will be glad to help again when the need arises, message me somehow so I know. Best of luck